# Adding custom argument to rest callback action

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I've ran into a problem programming a very basic tool for listing a few 'items' (and their respective price on the ingame Auction-House) from a video-game in a WPF-Window.

I get the price trend for a specific item (id) for the last 30 days from a REST-Service which delivers me something like this:

```
[{"timestamp":"1453892281000","buy":"3411","sell":"3791"},{...},...]
```

I'm requesting the price trend for around 100 items at a time (all async) and when handling the responseData I get a Class with all the fields of the response through RestSharp.
Now the problem is that I can't match the ResponseData to an Item as the Rest-Response doesn't deliver me one.
Is there a way to add an ID (integer) to the Action/Callback?

```
public static void getItemPriceHistory(int itemId, ListingsView view)
{
    var request = new RestRequest("itemPriceTrend/" + itemId);
    Action<List<RestItemPriceHistory>> ariph = view.processItemPriceHistory;
    executeAsync(request, ariph);
}

public static void executeAsync<T>(RestRequest request, Action<T> callback) where T : new()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    client.BaseUrl = BaseUrl;

    var asyncHandle = client.ExecuteAsync<T>(request, aresp => {
        callback(aresp.Data);
    });
}
```

I hope my problem is understandable if not, please say so and I'll try my best to provide a different explanation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out how I can do it:
By simply adding a second argument to the Action:

```
 Action<List<RestItemPriceHistory>, int> ariph = view.processItemPriceHistory;
```

And because of that ofcourse also at the callback:

```
callback(aresp.Data, itemId);
```

Seems so simpel now, not sure why I didn't try that earlier :)